# How to get attributes of associated models from within a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to essentially make an alias of an attribute in a related model within the first model.  Here are my models:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ingredients
end
```

The tags table has a column called "name."  I want to be able to call ingredient.name to get ingredient.tag.name.  I tried creating getter/setter methods for "name" in Ingredient but I'm not sure how to fetch the "name" attribute of Tag.

Comment: ingredient.tag.name should work. What comes of ingredient.tag.class? On a side note, shouldn't you be using a many to many for this?

Comment: Yes, ingredient.tag.name does work, but I want to be able to call ingredient.name to get the same result.  ingredient.tag.class returns the Tag class. Yeah, the class name of "tag" is a little misleading.  Suffice it to say, the mapping above is what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tag

    def name
      tag.name
    end
end
```

Comment: how to call that name in Ingredinent class itself?

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner equal to Abdullah's answer  would be to `delegate`:

```
delegate :name, :to => :tag
```

If you care about making things all on one line.

Comment: I am getting "Ingredient#name delegated to tag.name, but tag is nil" when using this on the edit path.

Comment: @weotch: well this simply means your tag is nil. You would get an `undefined method \`name' for nil:nilClass` if you tried Abdullah's way.